# How would I align text to the side of the header links on the same line?

Tags: html, css

How would I move the GSS from on top of the three links to the same line on the left side with a large space in between the two divs?

```css
.gssnav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-padding {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 30px;
}

.navlink {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
  border: transparent;
}

.navlink:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: primary;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header class="nav-padding">
    <div>
      <nav>
        <div class="gssnav">
          GSS
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
          <a href="index.html" class="navlink">Home</a>
          <a href="projects.html" class="navlink">Projects</a>
          <a onclick="smoothScrollTo('Links')" class="navlink">Links</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: That puts them all on the same line, but the GSS and Home link are really close to each other. Do you know how I could center the links on the right half and center the GSS on the left half? Or something close to that? tyvm

Answer (score 1):

Flex layout rules go on the parent element, and you'd use `justify-content: space-between` to spread things. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-padding {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 30px;
}

.navlink {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
  border: transparent;
}

.navlink:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: primary;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header class="nav-padding">
    <div>
      <nav>
        <div class="gssnav">
          GSS
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
          <a href="index.html" class="navlink">Home</a>
          <a href="projects.html" class="navlink">Projects</a>
          <a onclick="smoothScrollTo('Links')" class="navlink">Links</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use flexbox or css grid for this type of alignment... you can also use floats but i feel that flexbox or grid is much better...

```
/* edit  */
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap:  x rem; 
}
```

just replace **x** with the amount of space you want between the GSS and the links

Answer (score 0):

You can assign style to nav to reach that

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.gssnav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 10px;  
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav-padding {
  margin-top: 30px;  
}


.navbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 30px;
}

.navlink {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
  border: transparent;
}

.navlink:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: primary;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <header class="nav-padding">
    <div>
      <nav>
        <div class="gssnav">
          GSS
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
          <a href="index.html" class="navlink">Home</a>
          <a href="projects.html" class="navlink">Projects</a>
          <a onclick="smoothScrollTo('Links')" class="navlink">Links</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```